# Using GETDATE to return data after a certain date

Tags: sql

I need to return customers for a birthday promotion, and I want all customers who have a birthday today and haven't bought a product in the last 90 days. I can change the date to get different results but instead of changing the date each day manually, what function do I need so that it always updates with the current day?

WHERE [LBD] <= DateAdd(day, -90, '2018-02-19')

Comment: What database are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ANSI standard would be something like this:

```
where ldb < current_date - interval '90 day'
```

In SQL Server, you would write this as:

```
where ldb < dateadd(day, -90, getdate())
```